# How does Java know a File is a file or a directory?

Tags: java

How does Java know:

```
new File("C:\Directory")
```

is a directory?
and

```
new File("C:\Directory\file.txt")
```

is a file?

I'm asking because I use this:

```
File f = new File(directory_path)
f.mkdirs()
```

and later on, I check if the file is a directory and it returns false.

```
if(f.isDirectory())
```

Do I have to set the file to be a directory or does Java figure it out based on the lack of .extension?

Comment: Java asks the operating system.

Comment: So there's a few unknowns here - what is `directory_path` even set as?  What is the value you get back for `f.mkdirs()`?  (This could imply that you don't have permission to create a directory there and it *may* be failing silently.)

Comment: Note that just because a file name has no extension does not mean that it is a directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It consults the underlying file system which has an attribute that indicates whether a file is a directory or not.

From the code of `File.isDirectory`

```
return ((fs.getBooleanAttributes(this) & FileSystem.BA_DIRECTORY)
            != 0);
```

Comment: This answers the question as stated but likely doesn't address the OP's real concern, which is why their creation of a directory has failed.